# C# Send a class object through a socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I am attempting to send my custom packet object through a connected socket.
I serialize and turn the object into a byte array, which is then sent.
However, how can I determine the end of the buffer stream on the receiving end?

If I send text, I can add a simple "" tag at the end and check for that, however I am not sure would be a good approach in the case of this class object..

What is the common approach to this problem?

Comment: See my answer to the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37148335/5311735

Comment: The best way is length- and header-prefixing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35240061/3740093