# c# TcpListener receives strange characters in message

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm trying to read incoming messages using a `TcpListener`. I set up a listener and I get a message. But the message is very strange. I'm getting this:

```
▬♥♥¡☺?♥♥YÄÂb­ #ù÷"MDòs←ç→.ge ûjò8┼#i(♥→å:À#À'<À%À)g@À   À‼/À♦À♫32À+À/oÀ-À1z¢À↕▬‼ÿ☺:▬¶↨↑↓▬¶♠♥♠☺♣♥♣☺♦♥♦☺♦☻☻♥☻☺☻☻
```

The message is sent from another application (I don't have the source code of this application) over https (is it possible that the https is the problem?). Anyway, the listener I set up looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000);
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    listener.Start();

    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");

    Thread t = CreateThread(client, false);
    t.Start();
}

private static Thread CreateThread(TcpClient client)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[300];
        client.Client.Receive(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Received data: ");

        string value = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    });

    return t;
}
```

The message should be a valid xml tree. I'm using C# and .NET framework 4.5.2. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the application sends an HTTPS request, why are you using a TcpListener?

Comment: https is encrypted, **you do not want** to implement this yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster Tbh I'm not very familiar with HTTPS. What do you recommend instead of TcpListener?

Comment: An HttpListener.

Comment: You're listening a little too low in the OSI model.. unless you want to implement TLS yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, I'm looking very dumb now. Why didn't I think about that... I'll rewrite my application and set up an `HttpListener`. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said, it would appear that you're trying to get the data at a low level on the OSI model. Instead of using a TcpClient you can use a HttpClient to get the data from the application you're listening to.

Although it does depend on what your server is and how requests are handled.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Another solution is to use a StreamReader on your existing TCP connection, an example of that is in the question below. Although solution really depends on what your server it.

[How reading messages from Server? (tcp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517043/how-reading-messages-from-server-tcp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a web-service that uses soap/xml then use a web-service client ( add a Web Reference to your visual studio project )

Use an System.Net.Http.HttpClient or a System.Net.WebClient to download an xml file from a web-server.

No not try and decode encrypted web traffic using a TCP client.